# How to pass data from js or ts class to vue-component

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

as shown in the below code, in `DigitizePolygonInteractions.js`, in method `digitize()`, i have `drawEvt.on('drawend'`
what i want to do is, when the `drawend` event is called i want to send for example the `this.wkt-representation` to another vue component with extention `.vue`

how can i pass data from js class to vue component? is it ever possible please?

**to note**

```
i am using `optionsAPI`
```

**DigitizePolygonInteractions.js**

```
export class DigitizePolygonInteractions extends MapBuilder {
/**
 *
 * @param {*} moduleName string represents the id of the html tag <div id=></div>, in which the map will be visualized.
 * @param {*} mapInstance instance of the map object that on which digitization will be performed.
 */
constructor(moduleName, mapInstance) {
    super(moduleName);
    this.mapBuilderInstance = this;
    this.mapInstance = mapInstance;
    this.wktRepresenation = undefined;
    this.geoJSONRepresentation = undefined;
    this.layersCollector = new Array();
    this.interactionsEvtsCollector = new Array();
}

digitize() {
    if (this.layersCollector && this.layersCollector.length > 0) {
        this.removeCollectedLayers();
    }

    if (this.interactionsEvtsCollector && this.interactionsEvtsCollector.length > 0) {
        this.removeCollectedInteractionsEvts();
    }

    const source = this.mapBuilderInstance.getVectorSource();
    const rasterLayer = this.mapBuilderInstance.getRasterLayer();
    const vectorLayer = this.mapBuilderInstance.getVectorLayerFor(source, olColors.RGB_RED_LAVA, olColors.RGB_DIRTY_BLUE, 1, olColors.RGB_DIRTY_BLUE);
    const modifyEvt = this.mapBuilderInstance.getModifyGeomForSource(source);
    const drawEvt = this.mapBuilderInstance.getDrawGeomForSource(source, 'Polygon');
    const snapEvt = this.mapBuilderInstance.getSnapGeomForSource(source);
    this.mapInstance = this.mapBuilderInstance.addLayer(this.mapInstance, rasterLayer);
    this.mapInstance = this.mapBuilderInstance.addLayer(this.mapInstance, vectorLayer);
    this.mapInstance = this.mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.mapInstance, modifyEvt);
    this.mapInstance = this.mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.mapInstance, drawEvt);
    this.mapInstance = this.mapBuilderInstance.addInteractionEvtToMap(this.mapInstance, snapEvt);

    this.layersCollector.push(rasterLayer);
    this.layersCollector.push(vectorLayer);
    this.interactionsEvtsCollector.push(modifyEvt);
    this.interactionsEvtsCollector.push(drawEvt);
    this.interactionsEvtsCollector.push(snapEvt);

    drawEvt.on('drawend', e => {
        let feature = e.feature;
        let geom = feature.getGeometry();
        let wktformat = new WKT();
        let geoJSONformat = new GeoJSON();
        let wktRepresenation = wktformat.writeGeometry(geom);
        let geoJSONRepresentation = geoJSONformat.writeGeometry(geom);
        this.wktRepresenation = wktRepresenation;
        this.geoJSONRepresentation = geoJSONRepresentation;
        console.info(debugTag, 'drawEvt.on' + 'wktRepresenation:', this.wktRepresenation);
        console.info(debugTag, 'drawEvt.on' + 'geoJSONRepresentation:', this.geoJSONRepresentation);
    });
    return this.mapInstanc;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried emitting a custom event ?

Comment: @CruelEngine unforunately i could not find such a technique in google...would you please provide an example or a link

Comment: perhaps your google-foo is lacking - there are a myriad of results for *vuejs emit custom event*

Comment: @JaromandaX i check a tutorial about how to create customized event, but `$emit` needs to be invoked withing a template or html...which my .js class posted in the question does not have..any idea about that please

Comment: @CruelEngine  i check a tutorial about how to create customized event, but `$emit` needs to be invoked withing a template or html...which my .js class posted in the question does not have..any idea about that please

Comment: perhaps [this documentation](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus) may help - Personally, I would see if the last point, `Global state management, such as Pinia`, could provide a solution - but without knowing anything about your vue code, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: @Amrmsmb you could try emitting a vanilla js custom event using document.dispatchevent and listen to that event in your vue component